# search and replace functions to rename columns

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I have data frame like this

```
> d <- data.frame(team.aaa=1:3, team.aab=4:6, team.aac=7:9)
> d

#   team.aaa team.aab team.aac
#1        1        4        7
#2        2        5        8
```

and, desired output

```
d <- rename(d, c("team.aaa"="aaa_team", "team.aab"="aab_team", "team.aac"="aac_team"))
> d
#  aaa_team aab_team aac_team
#1        1        4        7
#2        2        5        8
#3        3        6        9
```

I could do it with rename string, but want to use search and replace option because of huge data volume
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example showed in the OP's post, it seems that the suffix part after the `.` should be the prefix and viceversa.  In that case, we can use `sub` to capture the characters that are not a `.` followed by `.`, then capture the rest of the characters (`(.*)`) and replace it with the backreference arranged accordingly.

```
names(d) <- sub("([^.]+).(.*)", "\\2_\\1", names(d))
names(d)
#[1] "aaa_team" "aab_team" "aac_team"
```

---

Or another option would be to split the string by `.` and then `paste` after reversing the order

```
sapply(strsplit(names(d), "[.]"), function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse="_"))
```

Or as @jota mentioned in the comments, if 'team' is always the first word, we can make it more compact with `sub`

```
sub("team\\.(.*)", "\\1_team", names(d))
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If "team" is always the first word:  `gsub("team\\.(.*)", "\\1_team", names(d), perl = TRUE)`

Comment: @ jota Thanks very much as you mentioned "team" is not always first word, I have some columns with names like "build_MS2_aab" my desired output will be "aab_build_MS2". Many thanks in advance