# How to search column names of a data frame by a character string and replace the entire column name with a new one (for downstream PCA)

Tags: r, search, replace, pca, factors

I am trying to create a PCA plot so I want to regroup my columns by batch (so that I cause use my column names as factors). I have read these two ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800704/r-remove-parts-of-column-name-after-certain-characters), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849594/search-and-replace-functions-to-rename-columns)) questions and have tried what they suggested, but it has not worked correctly (or I'm doing something wrong).

What I have is a dataframe with a few thousand columns with sample names like:

```
Measure    Br_LV_05_BC1_1_POS  Br_Lv_05_BC1_2_POS Br_Lv_05_BC1_3_POS Br_Lv_05_LR_1_POS Br_Lv_05_LR_2_POS
500               3000                8000                5000              1000              2000
600               4000                4000                4000              8000              8000 
700               5000                6000                4000              9000              8000 
800               6000                7000                8000              2000              1000
```

What I would like to do is perform a search and replace of all columns containing the string "BC1" and renaming that BC1 and same with "LR". This way I can have R use these columns as factors for PCA instead of the PCA measuring each column as an individual sample.

```
Measure  BC1    BC1     BC1     LR      LR
500      3000   8000    5000    1000    2000
600      4000   4000    4000    8000    8000 
700      5000   6000    4000    9000    8000 
800      6000   7000    8000    2000    1000
```

That way I can transpose the data (if needed) and cluster my PCA with the samples as factors. I hope I am correct in my thinking. Thank you kindly for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `base R` option with `sub` where wee extract the 4th word  from the column names and update it

```
names(df1)[-1] <-  sub("^([^_]+_){3}([^_]+)_.*", "\\2", names(df1)[-1])
names(df1)[-1]
#[1] "BC1" "BC1" "BC1" "LR"  "LR"
```

Or another option is `strsplit` at `_` and extract the 4th element

```
names(df1)[-1] <- sapply(strsplit(names(df1)[-1], "_"), `[`, 4)
```

---

We can also use `word` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
names(df1)[-1] <- word(names(df1)[-1], 4, sep="_")
```

NOTE: It is better not to have duplicate column names and it would be anyway changed in `data.frame` by the `make.unique`

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Measure = c(500L, 600L, 700L, 800L), Br_LV_05_BC1_1_POS = c(3000L, 
4000L, 5000L, 6000L), Br_Lv_05_BC1_2_POS = c(8000L, 4000L, 6000L, 
7000L), Br_Lv_05_BC1_3_POS = c(5000L, 4000L, 4000L, 8000L), Br_Lv_05_LR_1_POS = c(1000L, 
8000L, 9000L, 2000L), Br_Lv_05_LR_2_POS = c(2000L, 8000L, 8000L, 
1000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: So would it be better to melt and reshape the data first so that I have the measurement values as my columns and then clean my new Sample Batch column instead?

Comment: @vanish007 Not clear what you wanted.  I showed an option based on the expected output you showed

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll think about the next steps and how best to proceed.